# Swift: Using ObjectID of class for hashable protocol results in random behaviour in set.contains method. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: swift, set, hashable

I have a small number of instances of a custom class stored in a set. I need to check if a certain element is contained in that set. The criteria for a match must be the object's ID, not its content.

For simplification assume a class with an integer var as the only property, and two different instances of that class, both holding the number 1.

Directly comparing those instances should return true, but when a reference to the first is stored in the set, a query if the set contains a reference to the second one should return false.

Therefore I use the ObjectIdentifier of the object to generate the hash function required by the hashable protocol.

It is my understanding that the .contains method of a Swift Set uses the hash value first, and in case of hash collisions the equatable method is used as a fallback.

But in the following code, which can run in a playground, I get randum results:

```
class MyClass: Hashable {
    var number: Int
    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number == rhs.number
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
    }
}

var mySet: Set<MyClass> = []

let number1 = MyClass(1)
let secondNumber1 = MyClass(1)

number1 == secondNumber1        // true: integer values are equal, so are the wrapping classes
number1 === secondNumber1       // false: two different instances

mySet.insert(number1)

mySet.contains(number1)         // true
mySet.contains(secondNumber1)   // should be false but randomly changes between runs
```

If you run the above code in an XCode Playground and manually restart playground execution this gives different results for the last line on each run. The desired behaviour is to get "false" every time.

So what would be the correct way to achieve the described bahaviour?

Comment: Without spending a lot of time looking at it.  I'm wondering if, instead of `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {` you should override `hash` directly and return `ObjectIdentifier(self).hash` instead.  Having said that, why not use `hasher.combine(number)` instead?

Comment: From the documentation for `Hashable`: *"Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order."*. You need a different solution than `Hashable` or `Set`.

Comment: When I use `code`hasher.combine(number)`code` I would get the same hash value for identical numbers, but as I wrote in the first paragraph I want to check the set.contains method for identity, not equality.

Comment: @ rmaddy OK, but have you got any hint to what that solution could be?

Comment: Look into the `NSHashTable` class. You can create one based on object identity.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will look into that. First try in the playground code seems to work by using `var mySet = NSHashTable<MyClass>()` instead of Set. But, of course, my actual code is more complex, so I'll have to dig deeper to find out if there are any caveats …

Comment: After further examination it turns out, that NSHashTable does not conform to the Sequence protocol, so it is not possible to iterate over its items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, `Set` relies on `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` and `==`. It is invalid to have an unmatched pair of these. In your case, your equality is value-based (dependant upon `self.number`), whereas your hash is identity based. This isn't legal.

Your `mySet.contains(secondNumber1)` line is failing because `secondNumber2` might have a hash collision with `number1`. Whether a collision occurs or not is undefined, because [Swift uses a random seed to defend against hash-flood DDoS attacks](https://forums.swift.org/t/psa-the-stdlib-now-uses-randomly-seeded-hash-values/10789). If a hash collision does occur, then your equality operator (`==`) falsely identifies as `number1` as a match for `secondNumber1`

Instead, what you could do is implement a wrapper struct that implements equality and hashing based on an object's identity. The object itself could have its own value-based equality and hash, for other purposes.

```
struct IdentityWrapper<T: AnyObject> {
    let object: T

    init(_ object: T) { self.object = object }
}

extension IdentityWrapper: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: IdentityWrapper, rhs: IdentityWrapper) -> Bool {
        return lhs.object === rhs.object
    }
}

extension IdentityWrapper: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self.object))
    }
}
```

Using the IdentityWrapper in a set requires you to manually wrap objects before interacting with the set. It's performant (since struct don't need any array allocation), and most likely the struct is entirely inlined anyway, but it can be a little annoying. Optionally, you could implement a `struct IdentitySet<T>` which just wraps a `Set<IdentityWrapper<T>>`, which tucks away the wrapping code.

```
class MyClass: Hashable {
    var number: Int

    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }

    // Value-based equality
    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number == rhs.number
    }

    // Value-based hashing
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.number)
    }
}

var mySet: Set<IdentityWrapper<MyClass>> = []

let number1 = MyClass(1)
let secondNumber1 = MyClass(1)

number1 == secondNumber1        // true: integer values are equal, so are the wrapping classes
number1 === secondNumber1       // false: two different instances

mySet.insert(IdentityWrapper(number1))

print(mySet.contains(IdentityWrapper(number1))) // true
print(mySet.contains(IdentityWrapper(secondNumber1))) // false
```

Comment: Wouldn't the problem with hash collisions be the same? Obviously the hashValue that is generated from the ObjectID is prone to collisions, surprisingly, though.

Comment: "Wouldn't the problem with hash collisions be the same?" The hash collisions aren't the problem. It's the false positive in equality matching that follows that causes your bug. "the hashValue that is generated from the ObjectID is prone to collisions, surprisingly," Why is that surprising?

Comment: Imagine a hypothetical product. A product's hash is its "category". The equality of a product is value based. I.e. two boxes of pasta, in the same size, brand, etc. are equal, even if they're two seperate objects (instances), with differen identites. When you go to a store and you look for an item, you don't do a blind linear search, checking every product in the store, one by one, until you find a match. Instead, you use a heuristic, the product category, to derive the correct isle. You then do a one-by-one match within the limited set of objects in that isle/area.

Comment: Set and dictionary does the same thing. It narrows down the set of objects that need 1-by-1 searching, from all objects, down to only those objects with the same hash. If the hash is different, then there's no point checking them. For example, this is like looking for your desired pasta in the dairy fridge area. No bueno. Once the search pool is narrowed down, the 1-by-1 matching begins. If your equality matching doesn't match your hash function, you can end up with a false positive.

Comment: You hash function is identity based. Suppose that all boxes have an globally unique identity (akin to their `ObjectIdentifier`), and that you were looking for a specific box of spaghetti by its ID. Not just any spaghetti, but a single particular box. (suppose also that you had a way to map from object ID to isle number). By using your isle heuristic, you end up in the pasta section. While looking among the boxes of pasta, you use your equality comparison, which is erroneously value based. It says any 2 spaghetti boxes compare as equal.

Comment: When you start doing your 1-by-1 comparisons, you're using this equality comparison, and can mistakenly conclude that a box of spaghetti (which isn't your exact box you were looking for) is what you're looking for, because it too is spaghetti, and satisfies your value-based `==`. That's the bug you're experiencing. To fix this situation, your 1-by-1 process needs to be more specific, and check specific object ids, until those match. It's not sufficient for the object to merely also be spaghetti. Its object id needs to match the one you're looking for.

Comment: @MassMover Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, with your help, and some further web research, I now clearly understand how the concept of hash values in a set works - I did not fully understand before the concept of 'buckets', now I understand, that more often than not a query will be checked twice. While rmaddys hint towards NSHashTable seemed promising I did not have the time to check your wrapper solution, will do so. So, while I am still looking for a solution for my problem, as my question was actually: "What is wrong with my code?", you indeed answered it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: Actually, I re-phrased my question in a new thread to better reflect what I am truly looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814064/swift-how-can-i-handle-objects-selected-by-the-user As I wrote, I did not look deeper into your wrapper suggestion, but maybe there is a completely different approach to my actual intention.

Comment: And this is the cost of [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I put a lot of time into answering a question that wasn't your question. Next time, ask a question about your root problem, not a question about your attempt at a problem.

Comment: Actually, this is fine, your root problem is similar enough that this is still applicable. So why didn't you look into my wrapper suggestion?

Comment: Because coding is not my profession, I just do that in my spare time and didn't have the time to try it yet. Furthermore, I have no doubt that your solution works on my strapped down code, but in my original project it is probably a bit more complicated to adjust each part where the set is accessed. I understand it that you propose a convenient solution by additionally wrap the wrapper into the IdentitySet struct, but again, I am not a professional, so what to you is a simple exercise for me it takes time to understand and adapt it to my actual code. So please, be patient with me ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199085/discussion-between-alexander-and-massmover).